# Incompatibility when initializing a vector and assigning it to an 'externalptr' in R

Tags: r, types, initialization

I'm in trouble trying to make a for loop and assigning an "externalptr" (XML data type) to a vector.

```
current <- vector()

for(k in 1:length(dir())){
    current[k] <- htmlParse(dir()[k])
}
```

Throws me the following error:

```
Error in current[k] <- htmlParse(dir()[k]) : 
  incompatible types (from externalptr to logical) in subassignment type fix
```

I've tried to force a `current <- vector("mode=...")` for `list`, `expression`... etc but the error is still the same, and i can't force a mode of `externalptr`

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

(Complete code to explain why `current <- lapply(dir(), htmlParse)` doesn't work)

```
current <- vector()

for(k in 1:length(dir())){
  if(grepl(".xhtml$", dir[k])){
    current[k] <- htmlParse(dir()[k])
  }
}
```

It has to search only .xhtml files, so when I run that code it picks up whatever it finds.

I need the directory to stay the same, and this script has to run automatically over hundreds (maybe even thousands) of .XHTML documents. Maybe the best solution is to search for all the files before, and exclude them, and then doing someting like `lapply(dir()[-32, -56], htmlParse)`

Comment: Does `current <- lapply(dir(), htmlParse)` work?

Comment: Thanks for answering. No, finally it didn't work. `Error: failed to load external entity "css"`. Sorry for the edits

Comment: Make sure you use `lapply(current, free)`  after you are done with analysis on `current`.  This frees the memory from `htmlParse`

Comment: I found the error! The problem was that it extracts files that I don't want to extract. I edit my question and I complete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer in my case, for you to know:

```
dirs <- dir(pattern = ".xhtml$")
current <- lapply(dirs, htmlParse)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Look at the pattern argument to `dir()` to avoid a step

Comment: That's great! Thank you a lot!